# Obix Parser in Niagara

Tags: niagara-4

I would like to pull data from an Access Control System server (Kaba Exos 9300) to a third party java based system (Niagara Version 4.7). For the mentioned scope, I have to write Obix parser in my Niagara Server. Can anyone help me for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am going to suggest you need access to a copy of the Niagara N4.7 Developer Workbench (unless you already have this ?).

Once inside the workbench, there are two specific pieces of documentation inside the Workbench Help which might assist you. The first is docDeveloper, which gives you a complete guide for developing Niagara components. The second is by searching for 'oBIX' in the Help Search toolbar; this will list lots of items relating to oBIX, but the best one to read first is 'NiagaraAX oBIX Guide'.

I should also mention that there is an oBIX driver already written and available in N4. I don't know your exact circumstances, but perhaps you could use that ?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what parts you need from the question.  You shouldn't need to write any OBIX parsers in Niagara.  If you have an OBIX Server in your ACS server, then you can just use Niagara's OBIX driver to pull the data into Niagara; no development needed.  If what you need is to build the OBIX server in the Kaba server, there is a Java toolkit available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/obix/ which gives you some basic objects that your server could use.  It also bundles a client in, that could be used to independently test your server.